# Does Fpqc sheaf over category of rings imply representability

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, representable-functors, sites

I am trying to read the article "[Algebrization and Tannaka duality](https://arxiv.org/abs/1404.7483)" by Bharghav Bhatt. In Corollary 1.2, he says that given a qcqs algebraic space $X$ (I am interested in the case when $X=\mathrm{Spec}(A)$ for a complete local $\mathbb{C}$-algebra $A$) the functor from the category of rings to sets, which associates to a ring $R$, the set of $\mathrm{Spec}(R[[t]])$-points of $X$, is an fpqc sheaf. I wanted to ask, does this imply that there exists a scheme $Y$ that represents the functor? This seems to be true if $X$ is of finite type over a field as suggested by T. de Fernex in [Theorem 2.3](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1604.02728.pdf). My question is do I need $X$ to be of finite type over a field or can I take $X$ to be the spectrum of a local complete $k$-algebra, to get a similar representability result?

Comment: Let $X$ be a proper algebraic space over $\mathbb{C}$ which is not a scheme (Hironaka). Then $X$ is an fppf sheaf which is not representable by a scheme. Presumably it is also fpqc (I don't remember). So, the answer is presumably "no": an fpqc sheaf is not necessarily (representable by) a scheme.